# Bias-Variance trade off. Which is better?

Tags: machine-learning, variance, bias, overfitting

Suppose I had two models. One gave me a validation accuracy of 75% but showed high over fit (75% validation vs 87% train accuracy), the other had a lower accuracy 69% but less variance (69% validation vs 75% train accuracy)

Which should I choose? It makes sense to choose the higher accuracy since that's what I am after but it also makes sense that the higher variance lower accuracy model just got luckier with this validation set and in general but have accuracy less predictable.

Just as a note the validation size is small. I plan on doing a cross-validation but since it is time consuming to run I only want to do it on what I think is the best intermediate model.

Comment: You need to be careful with small validation sets. This paper goes into the details: http://ai.stanford.edu/~ang/papers/cv-final.pdf

Comment: I haven't gone through the entire paper yet (thanks for the source) but I just wanted to clarify that I plan was to pick a model, run a k-fold CV and if the difference between each fold was small (say the std was only 1-2%) then I could be confident that my accuracy wasn't just a lucky draw on a validation set. Is this a correct line of thinking?